# Problems launching openocd + GDB from Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to launch openocd + gdb via Make:

```
debug:
    (openocd interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f4x.cfg &); \
    arm-none-eabi-gdb $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf -ex "target remote localhost:3333" -ex "load"; \
    killall openocd; \
```

This works **until** I press ctrl+c to break:

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
^CError detected on fd 9
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Resource temporarily unavailable.
```

I'm guessing Make is intercepting the ctrl+c signal because if I copy the output of the `debug` command and paste it in my terminal (bash) I can break using ctrl+c without issues.

Is there a smart way to do this? I've tried wrapping the debug command in a shell script / python script, but haven't had any success

Comment: The way to do it is to not invoke interactive commands from a makefile.  If you want shortcuts for this, create a shell alias or shell script and use that instead.  Make is not designed to be used with interactive commands, so it won't handle management of the terminal properly when used with interactive commands.